# Adding data continuously to a csv file in python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Hi I am developing a cron job in python which query data for every 5 mins from mysql and write it to a csv file.

code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector
import csv 
import datetime
import schedule

x = datetime.datetime.now()
date = str(x.date() - datetime.timedelta(0))


connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='',user='',
                                     password='',auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')


cursor = connection.cursor()  

def job():
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = str(x.date() - datetime.timedelta(0))
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mydb.Data WHERE date = '%s'" % date)
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    c = csv.writer(open('test'+date+'.csv', 'w'))
    try:
        headers = ['id','p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','deviceType']
        c.writerow(i for i in headers)
        print('added headers')
        for x in results:
            c.writerow(x)
    except:
        print('CSV generation failed')



def cron_job():
    schedule.every(300).seconds.do(job)
    while True:        
        schedule.run_pending()


if __name__=='__main__':
    cron_job()
```

This runs the cron job every 5 minutes but, data is added to csv file only for the first time. Code is running without any exceptions. Why am i not getting the latest data in csv? Should i close the file or something everytime ?

Comment: Add more logging to the script and run again. Figure out whether the `job()` functions runs or not. If so, where is it stuck. etc.

Comment: Aren't you just overwriting the data in the file each time? I.e.: shouldn't `c = csv.writer(open('test'+date+'.csv', 'w'))` be `c = csv.writer(open('test'+date+'.csv', 'a'))`?

Comment: No need to check for pending jobs 1000s of times a second. Add `time.sleep(1)` after `run_pending()`, as suggested in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)

Comment: I want to overwrite the data in file each time, because my search query gives results of all the rows that were saved in table, till that point of time. so overwriting makes sense i guess